# How to add current custom taxonomy slug to body class

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, slug

My theme uses custom taxonomy called "kbsection" and there are lots of sections set up (instead of categories). There is also a custom post type and the posts are assigned to sections.

I need to style the header differently depending on what section(s) the post belongs to. So that the posts that belong to Section A have got a different header background than the ones belonging to Section B etc. If a post belongs to more than one section it doesn't matter which one it picks. It can always be the first one in the array.

I guess what I need for that is to get the current "section" slug and somehow add it as a body class. I've been trying lots of different methods and none seem to work for me. I've found the piece of code below, but of course that only works for categories and not for my "sections". Please help.

```
add_filter('body_class','add_category_to_single');
function add_category_to_single($classes, $class) {
    if (is_single() ) {
        global $post;
        foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category) {
            // add category slug to the $classes array
            $classes[] = $category->category_nicename;
        }
    }
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can follow similar approach with [`get_the_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms).
Here is the function.

```
function add_taxonomy_to_single( $classes ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        global $post;
        $my_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom-taxonomy' );
        if ( $my_terms && ! is_wp_error( $my_terms ) ) {
            foreach ($my_terms as $term) {
                $classes[] = $term->slug;
            }
        }
        return $classes;
    }
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_taxonomy_to_single' );
```

Don't forget to change the name of your custom taxonomy in above code. I used `custom-taxonomy` for example.

### EDIT 1:

To add first taxonomy name in body class here it the updated code.

```
function add_taxonomy_to_single( $classes ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        global $post;
        $my_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom-taxonomy' );
        if ( $my_terms && ! is_wp_error( $my_terms ) ) {
            $classes[] = $my_terms[0]->slug;
        }
        return $classes;
    }
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_taxonomy_to_single' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works great. I've got 2 more questions:


- Is it possible for it to output only the first slug from the array? At the minute it outputs all of them.

- Is it possible to do the same thing for the archive pages (sections) apart from single posts? So that if I'm on Section A, there would be a class "sectiona" assigned to the body.

Thank you

Comment: I added updated code for adding only first taxonomy to body class. Keep in mind that you cannot control the order of taxonomies, so you don't control which taxonomy will appear in body class out of many.

Comment: Thank you Robert. Your code works great. Regarding the second question - is there any way at all for me to distinguish which "section" page I'm on, so that I could use that in CSS to style the header for it?

Comment: WordPress by default adds taxonomy name in body classes on taxonomy archive pages. You don't need additional function for that.

Comment: Unfortunately my theme doesn't do that. Is there any way to add that in manually? Thank you

Comment: If your theme is not adding taxonomy name in body class then there might be some function (in theme or plugin) overriding this default behavior. Can't do much in this case.

Comment: This works great but one problem: It gets rid of the classes for all other pages that aren't single pages.

Comment: @desi @robert-hue there is an error in the second example of the code. The `return $classes;` needs to happen after the `if( is single() ){` statement, so between te last and the second last closing curly bracket. Otherwise it will overwrite/empty all existing classes from the theme and woocommerce for example.